# How can I see other photos taken around the same time?

Tags: google-photos

So I searched for and found a photo based on what it was (helicopter), but I want to see the other photos I took around that time (its context). Apple's Photos.app has something called "Show in Moment" when moving from search to library view. What's the easiest way to do this? Find its date and search for that? There's nothing simpler?

Comment: The default view of Google Photos is by date. It seems to me the simplest thing to do is get the date from the details of the photo you found, go back to the main view, and jump to that date.

Comment: Having to scroll to the right date seems a bit too much manual work I guess, they could easily do that so It seems like the features is somewhere that I am missing .